# How is JNI_CreateJavaVM invoked when running a java app from the command line

Tags: java, jvm

I am trying to understand the point of entry into **JVM**. After doing my research I have learnt that `JNI_CreateJavaVM` (at least in **HotSpot JVM**) is the method that is called to launch the JVM.

My question now is who calls the `JNI_CreateJavaVM` method ? I tried looking at the JDK source here [JDK7 Hotspot](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/hotspot/file/9b0ca45cd756). But it is not very clear and I was not able to find any '`int main`' method.

Lets say I create a simple java program and compile it to `Hello.java`. Now when I run '`java Hello`' from the command line, what exactly happens? What is the first method called?

**ANSWER**: @apangin definitely pointed me in the right direction(see comment below). The main method is located here [main method for java launcher](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/a006fa0a9e8f/src/share/bin/main.c). And from there it calls JLI_launch from where the JNI_CreateJavaVM method is invoked eventually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

java (java.exe) is the launcher - the small program written in C.
[The sources](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/a006fa0a9e8f/src/share/bin/java.c#l170) are in JDK repository, not HotSpot.

Java launcher first locates an installed JRE, creates a new virtual machine via `JNI_CreateJavaVM`, searches for the `main` method using JNI, and finally invokes this method with JNI `CallStaticVoidMethod` function.